# How do you create an Android "device user" programmatically (ie. with an API)?

Tags: android, system

I have an Android 4.4 device where I have created separate Users on the device (under Settings --> Device/Users). These are not Google accounts. They are accounts that live on the local device and work offline.

I'm aware of http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager.html but this only seems to let me get the current user.

I'd like to create a user, and possibly edit an existing one.

We're creating a system app, so it's fine if it's a low-level/hidden API.

I have searched the Internet high and low for this, and I'm really hoping the answer is not "you just can't."

Comment: If you have any better answer with you already, please do post it here so that others (like me) are helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use this method here: [DevicePolicyManager.createAndManageUser()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#createAndManageUser(android.content.ComponentName, java.lang.String, android.content.ComponentName, android.os.PersistableBundle, int))

It uses device admin privileges to create users. This method has been added in API 24 though.